# Kiip web sdk integration showing bad request error in console

Tags: node.js, bad-request, kiip

I just integrated KIIP SDK for web in my node js application and it works correctly . But the problem is it showing error on browser console on each page refresh, But this error does not affect working of this sdk, it works perfectly.

the errror message showing is,

'POST https://api.kiip.me/2.0/web/moment/?r=1426508956613 400 (Bad Request)'.

My kiip code integration is as follows,

1) Included the script file on head tag

2)Declared  the app key as global variable,

kiip_app_key='app-key from kiip site';

3) And intialized the kiip instance and invoked the method.

```
                var kiipInstance = new Kiip(kiip_app_key);
                kiipInstance.setTestMode();
                kiipInstance.postMoment('received offer');
```

Answer (score 0):

Andrew from Kiip here.A few things could be causing this:

1. The page is running from a local file or host. Solution: run the test page on a server.
2. The app is not submitted for live rewards. Solution: Submit for live rewards in the Kiip dashboard.
3. You're passing an incorrect app key. Solution: copy the app_key for the corresponding app from the Kiip dashboard and paste it as you're global variable.

Hope this helps,
Andrew

Comment: My app is already running on server and the app key is correct one. But it is running on test rewards .. let me check it replay soon.